# Multiple Queries in One Report - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

To keep this simple, lets say I have two tables.

The first is called **Employees**. It contains an *id* field and an *employee_name* field.

The second is called **Pay**. It contains an *id* field, an *employee_id* field and an *amount* field.

Now, I want to run a report on **Pay** that shows me how much each employee got paid by showing me only the *Employee.employee_name* and the *Pay.amount*.

Obviously, I'm going to have to take the *employee_id* field from the **Pay** table and match it up with the the *id* field from **Employees**, but I have no idea how to do that.

I know a little VBA and am pretty knowledgeable with SQL, but MS Access has me so confused I'm about to kill myself. I hate Access so much, I want to take it outside behind the middle school and get it dead.

This seems like a relatively easy problem, so someone has to know how to do this. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Is that helping you with the query for the report?

Comment: Showing the fields in Pay and Employees would make this a lot easier to answer. If there is pay history in Pay it is very different to a single value for each employee. Also the para "I know a little VBA and ..." isn't very constructive and may make people less inclined to help.

Comment: Are you lookinh to do this in a report or in a listbox on a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a query like this

```
SELECT Employees.Id, 
       Employees.employee_name, 
       Sum(Pay.amount) AS SumOfamount
FROM   Pay INNER JOIN 
       Employees ON Pay.employee_id = Employees.Id
GROUP BY  Employees.Id, 
          Employees.employee_name;
```

If you wish to make this as part of a list box, you can either save the sql as a query and set the *Listbox* property under the *Data Tab* called *RowSource* to the *Saved Query Name*, or you can set the *sql string* as the *RowSource*.

Remember to have a look at the Properties called Column Count ( *something like 0;3;3 0 being to hide the first column* ) and Column Heads (to include column headers, default *NO* )

If you widh to craete a *Report* using the data, you can go about this the same way ( *Saved Query or Use the Sql String* ). The Query/Sql String can be set in the *Data Tab* in the *Record Source* property. Now you can add the fields to the report from the *Existing Fields* window.

Comment: That may be the SQL, but it seems like the original questioner is unlikely to know what to do with it. I'll vote up your answer if you provide that detail.